# Accessing property of model instance from list and add them together?

Tags: python, django

Say I have a model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model)
property = models.IntegerField()
```

Say I have a function:

```
def func():
instance = Mymodel.objects.order_by('?')[0]
instance2 = Mymodel.objects.order_by('?')[0]
plan = [instance, instance2]
return plan
```

I want to use a for loop to add together the integers in the 'property' of the model instance and then output the sum into one of my templates?

I have tried the add filter but the problem is the amount of instances it will be adding together are dynamic so I can't simply do `myModel.0.property|add:myModel.1.property`

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Found a work around to this:

In your template just use the |length filter along with an if statement:

```
{% if instancelist|length == 2 %}
    {{ instancelist.0.property|add:instancelist.1.property }}
{% else %}
    {{ instancelist.0.property|add:instancelist.1.property|add:instancelist.2.property }}
{% endif %}
```

And so on.

Comment: Only of these two instances? Or the entire collection of `MyModel`s? Please do *not* write business logic in the template, that should be handled in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, just the two instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work around to this:

In your template just use the |length filter along with an if statement:

```
{% if instancelist|length == 2 %}
    {{ instancelist.0.property|add:instancelist.1.property }}
{% else %}
    {{ instancelist.0.property|add:instancelist.1.property|add:instancelist.2.property }}
{% endif %}
```